# How to extend a field in Laravel Nova?

Tags: vue.js, extends, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Nova and I'd like to create my own custom field based on this field : BelongsToMany. The idea is to get the code used for that field and then add my own.

I tried to create a custom field and then extend it (is it the right way ?) but then how can I edit the VueJS part of the field ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That's right. You can able to edit vuejs part of the filed as well. For info, you can check this docs https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/fields.html#fields